# Can I downgrade libopengl and do I need libopengl-dev?

Tags: nvidia, mouse, games, steam, opengl

I have run in to a problem which has become noticeable in a 3D game I play, that I have tracked to libopengl *(I think)*.

The problem is that there is a 3d scene where there are character models that as your mouse hovers/moves over them tooltips popup and you can interact with the characters by clicking on them to open character information windows.
Recently, and I'm not sure exactly when, but it feels like in the last couple of months at most, this mouse interaction feature has broken and no longer works.

The game itself offers the choice of using Vulkan or OpenGL renderers, and the Vulkan one still works but has other issues so I need to run the OpenGL renderer, however this issue is a game breaker for me.

So initially I thought it was the game at fault, but this morning I had to go back into an older version of Ubuntu for unrelated reasons, which obviously has an older libopengl, so I decided to try the game there on a hunch, and sure enough the mouse hover feature in the game works on that older libopengl, so it seems the problem is in fact with libopengl.

Now it has to be said I have nothing else to go on at pointing the finger at OpenGL other than the fact that the Vulkan renderer works. Plus the fact that the game itself has not updated since 1-12-2022, and the game has been working fine through January and most if not all of February.

The previous working version is Ubuntu 22.04 which uses

- libopengl0/jammy,now 1.4.0-1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
- libqt5opengl5/jammy-updates,now 5.15.3+dfsg-2ubuntu0.2 amd64 [installed,automatic]

But as I said this has only broken in the last month or two at most, so previous working version should include kinetic at some point pre mid February.

The current broken version is Ubuntu 22.10 which uses

- libopengl-dev/kinetic,now 1.5.0-1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
- libopengl0/kinetic,now 1.5.0-1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
- libqt5opengl5/kinetic,now 5.15.6+dfsg-1 amd64 [installed,automatic]

One thing I noticed is libopengl-dev. I have no idea if it could be causing the problems but I'm fairly certain I need it to develop flutter desktop applications as it seems to be a reverse dependency for at least libglu1 which is a dependency of the flutter desktop dev environment.

So is it possible to downgrade libopengl to a previous version so I can get back to a working version for my game?

Or is there anything else I can do to be more certain it is in fact libopengl that is causing the problem?

I'm running Ubuntu 22.10 with a fully upgraded system and nvidia-driver-525 525.85.05-0ubuntu0.22.10.1

**EDIT:** I have filed a bug with Ubuntu, but if anyone has any suggestions how to further isolate the problem to enhance the bug report or better yet fix the issue, please let me know.

Comment: Downgrading is not a viable option so many modules are interconnected. Use a VM and the old Ubuntu that works?

Comment: @David I guess I could but that feels like I'm hiding a problem on my system that could cause other problems down the line. And I'd like to report the bug to the devs if possible but not sure if I need more information to be able to do that.

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/report-ubuntu-bug.html.en